# I am not sure if it is alright vs I am not sure if it will be all right?

Tags: grammar

I understand that 'alright' is used in the same meaning and the context as 'all right', but is there a difference in meaning between those two sentences?

'I am not sure if it is all right'
'I am not sure, if it will be all right'

Can anyone elaborate on this one for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are almost completely synonymous, with the only difference really being that *alright* is more informal.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*alright*:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alright)

> : all right

In other words, it means the same thing.

Merriam-Webster's entry also adds the following:

**all right or alright?: Usage Guide**

> Although the spelling *alright* is nearly as old as *all right*, some critics have insisted *alright* is all wrong. Nevertheless it has its defenders and its users, who perhaps have been influenced by analogy with *altogether* and *already*. It is less frequent than *all right* but remains common especially in informal writing. It is quite common in fictional dialogue and is sometimes found in more formal writing.  **// the first two years of medical school were** ***alright*** **//** — Gertrude Stein

---

In addition to *all right* being more relatively common (although *alright* is not uncommon in its own right) and formal, there might also be another stylistic reason to use it. As in the explanatory paragraph above, if you are comparing two opposite things, there would simply be a greater sense of visual parallelism to describe them as *all right* and *all wrong* as opposed *alright* and *all wrong*.

Other people might have different personal reasons to use one over the other.

But all of that aside, the actual meaning of the two words is effectively identical.

Comment: The dictionary says alright and all right are used in the same context and for the same purpose, but i think your answer pretty much sums it up accurately. Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is asking :

1`I am not sure if it is all right.`

2`.I am not sure if it will be all right.`

His doubt is whether the change of the tense in the if clause makes any change in the meaning but not about the forms of *all ready* or *already*

I think the change of the tense  in the if clause makes some change in meaning.

The first sentence talks about the effect in the present time

The second sentence talks about the effect in the future time

However both the sentences are correct